# How to use Complex conjugate in GEKKO

Tags: python, controls, gekko, optimal

I have an optimal control problem with GEKKO. And I need take the complex conjugate of a variable. I know that GEKKO have method about .exp .log and so on, but I don't find the method about .conj

So how can I use conj. And in GEKKO, can variable be complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gekko allows complex numbers, but the solvers only work with real numbers so special structure needs to be added to deal with the real and imaginary parts. Here is an example that calculates the square root of a decision variable with an objective to maximize the imaginary part of the number. The complex conjugate is calculated.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var(2, lb=-9, ub=16)  # -9<=x<=16
b = m.if3(x, 0, 1)          # binary switch
s = m.Intermediate(m.sqrt(m.abs3(x)))  # sqrt(x)
r = m.Intermediate(b*s)     # real
i = m.Intermediate((1-b)*s) # imaginary

# Complex conjugate
r_conj = r  # real part is the same
i_conj = m.Intermediate(-i) # imaginary part

# Maximize imaginary part
m.Maximize(i_conj**2)
m.solve(disp=False)
print("Original:", r.value[0], '+', i.value[0], 'j')
print("Conjugate:", r_conj.value[0], '+', i_conj.value[0], 'j')
```

The result is:

```
Original: 0.0 + 3.0 j
Conjugate: 0.0 + -3.0 j
```

Comment: Thanks, I split the original complex equation into real and imaginary equations. Although it's little messy, it worked. I wonder are there any other tools can solve optimal control problem which are convenient and support complex numbers, I know some things like GRAPE, or unsupervised learning. I don't know if these have same problem about complex numbers.

Comment: Here is a nice overview of optimization with complex numbers, especially in machine learning: https://wandb.ai/darshandeshpande/complex-optimization/reports/The-Reality-Behind-the-Optimization-of-Imaginary-Variables--Vmlldzo2OTk3MDM I'm not aware of many solvers that handle complex numbers natively. For example, these are the solvers in Matlab that handle complex numbers: https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/complex-numbers-in-optimization-toolbox-solvers.html

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about GEKKO. Put in Python, you can use the .conjugate() method to get the complex conjugate of a number.

```
>>> x = 2 + 3j
>>> x.conjugate()
(2-3j)
>>> y = complex(10, 5)
>>> y.conjugate()
(10-5j)
```